# Using launchd to start JOSM with JOSM-Remote-Control

Tags: http, get, launchd

I use JOSM for OSM editing with the remote control. It works via links like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8111/load_and_zoom?left=8.19&right=8.20&top=48.605&bottom=48.590&select=node413602999
```

JOSM receives its commands via http GET.

I've created the following com.josm.plist. It starts JOSM when opening an url like the url mentioned above but then josm doesn't receive the information from the url.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.josm</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>open</string>
        <string>/Applications/JOSM.app</string>
    </array>
    <key>inetdCompatibility</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Wait</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
    <key>SessionCreate</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Sockets</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Listeners</key>
        <array>
        <dict>
            <key>SockServiceName</key>
            <string>8111</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SockServiceName</key>
            <string>8112</string>
        </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I cant figure out why the information from the url doesn't reach JOSM but i guess it gets lost somehow. Any hints what the problem might be?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your load_and_zoom example.  I checked it out and it works fine.  Here's some things to check.

- You may have to open ports 8111 and 8112 on your firewall.
- If the firewall is not the issue, then there may be something else listening on the ports.
- I've noted some issues from www.openstreetmap.org and the JOSM edit drop down option. It works better in Chrome than Firefox.  The OSM.org issue may have to do with https.  The Apple browser can be an issue to investigate if you are using the Apple browser to launch the report control command.
- I looked at the Firefox issue by accessing https://127.0.0.1:8112.  Firefox is blocking my access because of a [TLS Error issue](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/tls-error-reports).  The message is "An error occurred during a connection to 127.0.0.1:8111. SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length. (Error code:ssl_error_rx_record_too_long) The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified."  In my case, I believe Chrome is the only work around that I have right now.  Josm uses a self signed certificate.
- The [OSM Help Thread on JOSM remote control issues](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/2208/how-do-i-enable-the-remote-control-in-josm) also points out potential remote control problems with [Application Boundaries Enforcer, ABE, security features](https://noscript.net/abe/). gnurk says, "You will find the ABE settings under the Advanced tab in the NoScript options dialog."  The [OSM Help Thread](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/2208/how-do-i-enable-the-remote-control-in-josm) also provides ABE configuration examples for OSM related sites.
- You might want to run JOSM in a command/terminal.  I've noted that remote control is the last INFO parm to display in the window before I see the JOSM splash screen.
- You have a delay in your plist file but is it long enough? But I am not sure if you are trying to start up JOSM and expect to have remote control fire from the command line. JOSM does have other load options to run on the [command line options](https://josm.openstreetmap.de/wiki/Help/CommandLineOptions) but the options do not allow you to create geometries.
- The command window is useful in that you can see JOSM is listening for remote control commands.

> ```
> ...
> INFO: RemoteControl::Accepting remote connections on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8111
> INFO: RemoteControl::Accepting remote connections on /127.0.0.1:8111
> INFO: RemoteControl::Accepting secure remote connections on /127.0.0.1:8112
> INFO: RemoteControl::Accepting secure remote connections on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8112
> ...
> ```